# When I try to post 200 plus records through model list from view to controller it is showing always null in controller HTTP POST Action in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to submit a model list from view to controller. It is working fine for below 200 records in list. But when I try to post more than 200 records through the model object from view to controller it is always showing null in controller.

```
The code which I have written as follows -

**In Model -**


    public partial class SlsaudtMerchId
        {
            [Key]`enter code here`
            [Required]
            public int Company { get; set; }enter code here
            public int Store { get; set; }
            public string TermLoc { get; set; }
            [Key]
            [Required]
            public int TermId { get; set; }
            public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
            public string Inactive { get; set; }
        }
        public class SlsAuditMerchId_Cust
        {
            /// <summary>  
            /// To hold list of orders  
            /// </summary>  
            public List<SlsaudtMerchId> SlsaudtMerchIds { get; set; }
    
        }
    
    **In View -**
    
  @model PostListData.Models.SlsAuditMerchId_Cust    
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "PlaceOrder";
    }
    
    <h1>PlaceOrder</h1>
    
    <p>
        <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
    </p>
    <div>
    
    </div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10 text-right">
                    <input type="button" value="Add Product" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Product Code
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Product Name
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Quantity
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Price
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Total Amount
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        @{
                           
                            int i = 0;
                            foreach (var item in Model.SlsaudtMerchIds.ToList())
                            {
    
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
    
    
                       @Html.EditorFor(o => o.SlsaudtMerchIds[i].Company, new { @id = "ItemCode_" + i })
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.SlsaudtMerchIds[i].Store, new { @id = "ProductName_" + i })
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.SlsaudtMerchIds[i].TermLoc, new { @id = "Qty_" + i })
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    `enter code here`@Html.EditorFor(o => o.SlsaudtMerchIds[i].TermId, new { @id = "Price_" + i })
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.SlsaudtMerchIds[i].Updated, new { @id = "Updtd_" + i })
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.SlsaudtMerchIds[i].Inactive, new { @id = "inactv_" + i })
                                                </td>
    
                                            </tr>
    
                                i++;
                            }
                        }
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10 text-center">
                    <input type="submit" value="Place Order" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    
    **In Controller :**
      public IActionResult Index()
            {
                List<SlsaudtMerchId> objOrder = new List<SlsaudtMerchId>()
                       //ObjOrder will be populated from API
                SlsAuditMerchId_Cust ObjOrderDetails = new SlsAuditMerchId_Cust();
                ObjOrderDetails.SlsaudtMerchIds = objOrder;
                return View(ObjOrderDetails);
            }
           [HttpPost]
          `enter code here`  public IActionResult Index(SlsAuditMerchId_Cust MerchId)
              // It is sowing null for above 200 records`enter code here`
            {
    
    
                return View();
            }
```

I don't understand what the mistake I am doing here. When I try to submit below 200 (175-180 ) records through the model list it submit successfully the list argument in controller is capturing the all 175 record list. But When I try to increase the count of the list it is showing null in list argument in controller.

Please help me,
Thanks in advance

Soumen.

Comment: Try to add following code in your startup:`services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.MaxModelBindingCollectionSize = 100000;
        });

        services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
            options.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            options.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
        });`

Comment: Thank you sir, You are lifesaver.it is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add following code in your `startup`

```
services.AddMvc(options => {
   options.MaxModelBindingCollectionSize = 100000;
});          
services.Configure<FormOptions>(options => {
  options.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue; 
  options.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;             
  options.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
});
```